# What is the minimum pumping length of the following languages?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

How to determine the minimum pumping length of union of two languages?  How do I proceed after determining the individual pumping lengths?

1. 0*1+0+1* U 10*1 - Here the minimum pumping length of the first expression is 1 and of the second is 2. I am  stuck here ! Now what do I do?
2. 001 U 0*1* : The min PL of first expression is 4 and of the second is 1 , now what's the overall minimum PL?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that a pumping length for a language $K$ is a constant $c_K$ such that each string that has at least that language can be pumped within the language. Here "pumped" can remain somewhat abstract: it may be regular or context-free "uvwxy" pumping for instance.

It is clear that we can take $c_{K\cup L}\le \max\{c_K,c_L\}$. Any string in $K\cup L$ of at least this length can be pumped within either $K$ or $L$ depending or where it comes from.

It seems we cannot say more than that. The main reason is that we can pump one language into the other. Look at a variant of your last example. If $K$ is finite, say it contains all words shorther than $m$, then $c_K = m$, as no word in $K$ can be pumped. Let $L$ be the complement of $K$ containing all words of length at least $m$. Then $c_L = m+1$ (assuming that pumping incluses "pumping down" where we obtain shorter strings). However $c_{K\cup L}=c_{\Sigma^*}=1$.

I am afraid that for concrete examples you have to do a separate analysis.

Comment: The tags to the question suggest it's asking about the pumping lemma for regular languages. (Indeed, in practical terms, anyone who says "pumping lemma" without saying which one probably means the pumping lemma for regular languages, rather than the one for context-free languages.)

Comment: what is the min pumping length for 001?

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are right, but before I realized this I concluded it did not matter. Here I only use at some point that zero-pumping (deleting from the word) is included.

Comment: For finite languages we set the pumping length to be larger than the largest string, so that the statement "each string in the language at least as long as" becomes false. Finite languages cannot be pumped in the usual way, but still satisfy the pumping lemma because of this.